# Publish Jenkins Job build status to Gitlab commit with Jenkins Pipeline job

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have integrated my Gitlab CE version 9.3.5 with jenkins version 2.60.1 .

I am able to trigger builds with Gitlab webhook and publish the result back to the commit with a jenkins freestyle job.

I was wondering how can i achieve the same with jenkins pipeline job as every article on the above integration works with jenkins freestyle job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I follow the documentation about the [Gitlab Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin), you should be able to use the  `gitlabCommitStatus` method which will publish the status of the build steps declared after (here is an example from the doc) :

```
node() {
    stage 'Checkout'
    checkout <your-scm-config>

    gitlabCommitStatus {
       <script that builds, tests, etc. your project>
    }
}
```

If this is not enough, you also have the possibility to use `updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'pending'` to control more precisely which state you're sending to the gitlab instance.

Comment: this actually worked for me but on failure the gitlab smtp server fires an email to all the project contributors about the build failure. What if I want to override this sometime in future?

Comment: @Alex.DA nice to have helped you :) For your other problem, I think it is related to a configuration option in your Gitlab instance, no more related to jenkins

Comment: This appears to also need a `gitLabConnection` specified so it knows which Gitlab to update. So `properties([gitLabConnection('foo')])` or `gitlabCommitStatus(connection: gitLabConnection('bar'))`.

Comment: @CédricJulien So you mean updateGitlabCommitStatus will only provide more control over status ? Or When we should use updateGitlabCommitStatus Vs gitlabCommitStatus Vs gitlabBuilds ?